# How can you calculate percent error in tensor approximations?

Tags: error-estimation, matrix

I have a matrix `A` which is an approximation to the known matrix `B`. Both matrices are square, 3x3 matrices and, in this case, are symmetric. Is there a 'best' method for calculating percent error in the approximation? I had been using the sum the 'sum of squares' error for all entries divided by the sum of 'sum of squares' of the true matrix,
`pct_err = sum(sum( (A-B).^2 ))/(sum(sum(B.^2))` 
and realized that this is simply the square of `norm(A-B,2)/norm(B,2)` which gives drastically different percent error estimates.

How should I go about calculating percent error between two matrices, or maybe more generally, two tensors?

EDIT:
Thanks to some of the comments, I now recognize the difference between the 2-norm and the Frobenius norm. In either case, however, the type of norm I am taking is of relatively small consequence. The bigger question is how to represent the percent error of a 2nd rank tensor correctly.

Comment: There is no "correct" way. You have to pick your favorite measure of beauty and use that.

Answer (score 1):

`norm(A,2)` returns the largest singular value of `A` not the square root of the sum of squares of its elements.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain that a bit more? The definition of the matrix p-norm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) is not the largest singular value. When I wrote `norm(A,2)` I was speaking about the 2-norm, even though I was using MATLAB's syntax. Even in MATLAB, however, it appears, that `norm(A,2)` is still using the 2-norm (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html).

Comment: I will add that I see that the largest singular value returns the same as the `norm(A,2)` command in MATLAB, but `sum(sum( A.^2 ))^0.5` returns something very close. Could you possibly explain the difference and why they are so similar?

Comment: The 2-norm of a matrix is not the square root of the sum of the squares of its elements, it's defined as $max\{\|Ax\|_2 : \|x\|_2 = 1\} $, which is the same as the largest singular value. You can see a simple difference by comparing the sum of squares for a matrix with only ones on the diagonal. The MATLAB `norm(A,2)` returns 1, and the square root of the sum of the squares returns `sqrt(1/n)` where `n` is the dimension of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you want in MATLAB is `norm(A, 'fro')`, [the Frobenius norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm).